# User Authorization not working for Mean.JS

Tags: javascript, acl, mean, meanjs

I’m using mean.js to let registered users access content. It’s sort of working. I can change isAllowed to !isAllowed to let people see the content. The problem is that content is not authorized when the user logs in. The articles example works fine. But when I create my own section, logged in users can’t access pages!

So basically if I log in, I get message: 'User is not authorized' if I try going to localhost:3000/requestoffwork

If I log in and change isAllowed to !isAllowed, I can access it

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */
var acl = require('acl');

// Using the memory backend
acl = new acl(new acl.memoryBackend());

/**
 * Invoke Articles Permissions
 */
exports.invokeRolesPolicies = function () {
  acl.allow([{
    roles: ['admin'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: '*'
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: '*'
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['user'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/requestoffwork',
      permissions: '*'
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get']
    }]
  }, {
    roles: ['guest'],
    allows: [{
      resources: '/api/articles',
      permissions: ['get']
    }, {
      resources: '/api/articles/:articleId',
      permissions: ['get']
    }]
  }]);
};

/**
 * Check If Articles Policy Allows
 */
exports.isAllowed = function (req, res, next) {
  var roles = (req.user) ? req.user.roles : ['guest'];

  // If an article is being processed and the current user created it then allow any manipulation
  if (req.article && req.user && req.article.user.id === req.user.id) {
    return next();
  }

  // Check for user roles
  acl.areAnyRolesAllowed(roles, req.route.path, req.method.toLowerCase(), function (err, isAllowed) {
    if (err) {
      // An authorization error occurred.
      return res.status(500).send('Unexpected authorization error');
    } else {
      if (isAllowed) {
        // Access granted! Invoke next middleware
        return next();
      } else {
        return res.status(403).json({
          message: 'User is not authorized'
        });
      }
    }
  });
};
```

This is the route

```
app.route('/requestoffwork').all(managementPolicy.isAllowed)
    .get(management.list)
    .post(management.submit);
```

And here's the data for the user

```
{"_id":"5788fe46587a1c0b07a04078","displayName":"","provider":"local","__v":0,"created":"2016-07-15T15:16:22.625Z","roles":["user"],"profileImageURL":"modules/users/client/img/profile/default.png","email":"email@gmail.com","lastName":"","firstName":”"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you add the permissions to the client side routes ass well ?

In `modules/youModule/client/config/youModule.client.routes.js` add this:

```
  function routeConfig($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('yourState', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/requestoffwork',
        template: '<ui-view/>',
        data: {
          roles: ['user'], //here you must specify the roles as well
          pageTitle: 'requestoffwork'
        }
      })
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would upvote this suggestion if I had 15 reputation points, @Luke Kroon. The problem was the "de-serialize user" portion in the admin module. I added that to my new module and it worked! I hope someone reads this and finds it helpful. Sorry for not upvoting, Luke :)